# How do we store the data in a network model and Hierarchical model?

Tags: database, rdbms

how do I store the below table data in hierarchical and network data model?
[image]

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts & ask a specific question where you are stuck after researching.

Comment: @  philipxy could you please tell me how the data stored in table in hierarchical data model and network data model

Comment: Here's a link to an article I wrote a while back on both the IMS JDBC API and how it maps to the physical data layout. The first couple figures would be what you're looking for. http://ibmsystemsmag.com/mainframe/administrator/ims/jdbc-api/

Comment: @ must immediately precede a username, don't follow it by a space. Please act on comments, don't ignore them & don't use a comment to repeat your question.

Comment: @philipxy ok I got the answer

Answer (score 3):

No, RDBMS do not "store" data in "table format".  "table format" is +- **how those systems present their data to their users**, i.e. it is [part of] the **structure of the API they expose**.  The actual storing is up to the DBMS and is none of your business.

The general concept of the API of graph-based systems is that you have several "record types" (corresponds +- to tables), that of each one you can have a "current occurrence" in your program (/run unit) and that for each of those you can ask the system to fetch a related occurrence of another or the same type.  E.g. you can ask for the "next" occurrence of the same record type, in some ordering understood by the system.  Or you can ask for the "first" occurrence of type Y for some given current occurrence of type X and for some relationship between X and Y understood by the DBMS.

For more detail, google for user guides of high-grade professional graph systems such as IMS or IDMS.